# opencv python error: assertion failed:size.width>0&&size.height>0

Tags: python, opencv

**Code:**

```
import cv2

trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
img = cv2.imread("rdj_1.png")#RDJ.png
cv2.imshow('', img)
cv2.waitKey()

print("Hello world!")
```

**Error:**

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-m9hy83n6\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: Check size with `height, width = img.shape[:2]` after reading. Does the file exist (`isfile(filename)`)? Is it readable (`access(filename, R_OK)`)? Is it an image?

Answer (score 1):

error: (-215)" means that an assertion failed. In this case, cv::imshow asserts that the given image is non-empty:
if the file does not exist, then cv2.imread() will return None; it does not raise an exception.
Thus, the following code also results in the "(-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0" error

```
img = cv2.imread('no-such-file.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

Check to make sure that the file actually exists at the specified path. If it does, it might be that the image is corrupted, or is an empty image.

also your code should be looking something like

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Filepathtoimage\image.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```